# Considerations for building SysV or Upstart compatible Bash scripts

Tags: bash, service, daemon, init.d, upstart

I've just knocked out a quick script for keeping a slave web server in sync with a master using rsync. (https://github.com/simonjgreen/liveFolderSync/blob/master/liveFolderSync.sh)

I'd like to make this run on boot and be controllable via the usual /etc/init.d/... or service commands, however this is an area I've always fallen down in. I find both init.d scripts and upstart scripts horrendously confusing, and can't find a guide anywhere for starting from scratch.

The only control I'd like to have over it is start/stop/restart. Obviously later I will move the config into a separate file in /etc but that's already on the cards so outside the scope of this question.

Any pointers/advise and best practices would be helpful. I should add that I'm doing this on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get started with Sys V init scripts, I suggest the following links:

1. [Linux: How to write a System V init script to start, stop, and restart my own application or service](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html)
2. [Writing System V init scripts for Red Hat Linux](http://sensi.org/~alec/unix/redhat/sysvinit.html)
3. [Ubuntu Bootup Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto)

For instructions specific to **Upstart**, I would recommend starting with:

- [Getting Started](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html)
- [The Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

At present, there are also [129 questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=upstart) on AskUbuntu, several of which will point you in the right direction:

- [What Events are available for Upstart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28281/what-events-are-available-for-upstart)
- [Want to make an Upstart script, need help and advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22099/want-to-make-an-upstart-script-need-help-and-advice)

Comment: Link #2 appears to be dead, but I found something helpful: http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/Startup_and_shutdown/creating_your_own_init_scripts.shtml